# How do I correctly name ParseResults?

Tags: pyparsing

I like to name the entities in my grammar so I can access them using the `as_dict()` feature of `ParseResults`. But somehow it is not obvious to me where exactly I should "group" and "name" them. This often results in some kind of trial and error process.

To make more clear what I mean I tried to strip down the problem to a minimal example:

If we define an identifier that is labelled with "I" and holds the name of the identifier:

```
from  pyparsing import *

identifier = Word(alphas,nums)
gid        = Group(identifier("I"))
idg        = Group(identifier)("I")

t=gid.parseString("x1")
print(t.as_dict(), t.as_list())
t=idg.parseString("x1")
print(t.as_dict(), t.as_list())
```

results in:

```
{} [['x1']]
{'I': ['x1']} [['x1']]
```

which suggests that I should first "Group" then "name" the identifier.

However if I use a sequence of these (named "P") it's vice versa, as this (continued) example shows:

```
prog= [
    Group(ZeroOrMore(gid)).setResultsName("P"),
    Group(ZeroOrMore(idg)).setResultsName("P"),
]

s = "x1 x2"

for i in range(0,len(prog)):
    t=prog[i].parseString(s)
    print(t.as_dict(), t.as_list())
    for v in t.P:
        print(v.as_dict(), t.as_list())
```

which outputs:

```
{'P': [{'I': 'x1'}, {'I': 'x2'}]} [[['x1'], ['x2']]]
{'I': 'x1'} [[['x1'], ['x2']]]
{'I': 'x2'} [[['x1'], ['x2']]]
{'P': {'I': ['x2']}} [[['x1'], ['x2']]]
{} [[['x1'], ['x2']]]
{} [[['x1'], ['x2']]]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or did I just misunderstand named results?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: You might get some insights into this using `ParserElement.create_diagram()` - be sure to set `show_results_names=True` and `show_groups=True` this might help you better visualize where the names and groups are going.

Comment: Well, I ran create_diagram on these 4 expressions, and they were not as insightful as I'd hoped. I'll follow up with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to pyparsing! Grouping and results names are really important features to get a good understanding of, for making parsers with useful results, so it's great that you are learning these basics.

I had suggested using `create_diagram()` to better see the structure and the names for these expressions. But they are almost too simple for the diagrams to really show much. As you work with pyparsing further, you might come back to using `create_diagram` to make parser railroad diagrams for your pyparsing parsers.

Instead, I replicated your steps, but instead of using `results.as_dict()` and `results.as_list()` (where `results` is the pyparsing `ParseResults` value returned from calling `parse_string()`), I used another visualizing method, `results.dump()`. `dump()` prints out `results.as_list()`, followed by an indented list of the items by results name, and then by sub-lists. I think `dump()` will show a little better how names and groups work in your expressions.

One of the main points is that `as_dict()` will only walk named items. If you had an expression for two identifiers like this (where only one expression has a results name:

```
two_idents = identifier() + identifier("final")
```

Then `print(two_idents.parse_string("x1 x2").as_list())` will print:

```
['x1', 'x2']
```

But `print(two_idents.parse_string("x1 x2").as_dict())` will only show:

```
{"final": "x2"}
```

because only the second item has a name. (This would even be the case if the unnamed item was a group containing a sub-expression with a results name. `as_dict()` only walks items with results names, so the unnamed containing group would be omitted.)

Here's how `dump()` would display these:

```
['x1', 'x2']
- final: 'x2'
```

It shows that a list view of the results has 'x1' and 'x2', and there is a top-level results name 'final' that points to 'x2'.

Here is my annotated version of your code, and the corresponding `as_dict()` and `dump()` output from each:

```
from pyparsing import *

identifier = Word(alphas, nums)

# group an expression that has a results name
gid = Group(identifier("I"))

# group an unnamed expression, and put the results name on the group
idg = Group(identifier)("I")

# groups with the results name "P" on the outer group
prog0 = Group(ZeroOrMore(gid)).setResultsName("P")
prog1 = Group(ZeroOrMore(idg)).setResultsName("P")

# pyparsing short-cut for x.set_name("x") for gid, idg, prog0, and prog1
autoname_elements()

s = "x1 x2"
for expr in (gid, idg, prog0, prog1):
    print(expr)  # prints the expression name
    result = expr.parse_string(s)
    print(result.as_dict())
    print(result.dump())
    print()
```

Gives this output:

```
gid
{}
[['x1']]
[0]:
  ['x1']
  - I: 'x1'

idg
{'I': ['x1']}
[['x1']]
- I: ['x1']
[0]:
  ['x1']

prog0
{'P': [{'I': 'x1'}, {'I': 'x2'}]}
[[['x1'], ['x2']]]
- P: [['x1'], ['x2']]
  [0]:
    ['x1']
    - I: 'x1'
  [1]:
    ['x2']
    - I: 'x2'
[0]:
  [['x1'], ['x2']]
  [0]:
    ['x1']
    - I: 'x1'
  [1]:
    ['x2']
    - I: 'x2'

prog1
{'P': {'I': ['x2']}}
[[['x1'], ['x2']]]
- P: [['x1'], ['x2']]
  - I: ['x2']
  [0]:
    ['x1']
  [1]:
    ['x2']
[0]:
  [['x1'], ['x2']]
  - I: ['x2']
  [0]:
    ['x1']
  [1]:
    ['x2']
```

Explanations:

- `gid` is an unnamed group containing a named item. Since there is no top-level named item, `as_dict()` returns an empty dict.
- `idg` is a named group containing an unnamed item. `as_dict()` returns a dict with the outer with the single item 'x1'
- `prog0` is 0 or more unnamed groups contained in a named group. Each of the contained groups has a named item.
- `prog1` is 0 or more named groups contained in a named group. Since the named groups all have the same results name, only the last one is kept in the results - this is similar to creating a Python `dict` using the same key multiple times. `print({'a':100, 'a':200})` will print `{'a': 200}`. You can override this default behavior in pyparsing by adding `list_all_matches=True` argument to your call to `set_results_name`. Using `list_all_matches=True` makes the result act like a `defaultdict(list)` instead of a `dict`.

Please visit the pyparsing docs at https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and some additional tips in the pyparsing wiki at https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki .

Comment: Dear @PaulMcG. Thank you so much for you detailed answer (and for pyparsing in general!) I still have one question: 0 or more unnamed groups in a named group will be represented as a list, while 0 or more named groups in a named group will be put into a dict? Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of. pyparsing's lists and dicts are all internal to a class called `ParseResults` and that is actually what you get back. Depending on how you use `set_results_name`, ParseResults can have list behavior _and_ dict behavior. So you don't need to call `as_list` to iterate through the matched values, nor `as_dict` to access values by name. _And_ if the name is a valid Python identifier, results can be accessed like fields in an object.  If you took the result from `prog0.parse_string` as `res`, you could access the values as `res.P[0].I`. In the docs link that I sent, look up `ParseResults`.

Comment: This is IMHO far too complex. It would be great if the tree handling would be much simplified so that nodes and properties of the tree elements can be named easily and a visitor is available that returns each node with the full string for the token of the node, the label of the node and the child elements thus making the Abstract Syntax Tree available for easy navigation. The current solutions needs to much explanation and IMHO isn't intuitive at all.